# How to do conditional sum in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Question originally [posted in Spanish, on es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300253/suma-condicional-en-crystal-report), by [Sebastián Miranda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/63378/sebasti%c3%a1n-miranda):

> I am working with Crystal Report since Visual Studio 2017, I was asked
> to make a sum to group, I have 3 options: Credit Notes, Ballot and
> Invoice.
>
> The first thing I did was to create a Formula Field with the name
> **NumberValorCif** to convert the ICIF Value that I have to numeric with **ToNumber ()**. I saved this and created another formula field
> named **SumCIFCredito** that has the following code:
>
> ```
> If {CobroPorcentaje.TipoDoc} = 'Credit Notes'
> then {@NumberValorCif}
> else 0
> ```
>
> I saved, compiled and ran the application and it worked without any
> problems ... but. I wanted to do the same for **SumCIFBoleta**:
>
> ```
> If {CobroPorcentaje.TipoDoc} = 'Ballot'
> then {@NumberValorCif}
> else 0
> ```
>
> But I don't add anything. I'm missing something? or I have to create
> another variable.
>
> I hope someone can help me.
>
> Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you simply need to add the actual SUM of that new formula.

Place the new formula in the detail section, select it, hit the Sigma button to sum it, and elect to generate subtotals for your Grouping level.